# Is it possible to not know if a random variable is continuous or not?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Suppose I have a sample of a random variable, $X$ but I do not know if the distribution is continuous or discrete. First of all is this possible?

Second if it is possible how could I determine if $X$ is continuous from a set of iid random variables $X_1, ... X_n$?

Comment: Suppose I gave you a random variable $X$ and told you nothing else about it?  Could you figure out if it was continuous or not?  You cannot determine continuity from a finite set of evaluations, you can't even assign a probability to it being continuous given this finite set of evaluations.

Comment: Even if you had a large sample and every value was 0 or 1? Are you saying you can even predict if it were continuous or not with some probability?

Comment: Correct, after all it could still take the rest of $\bf R$ with some vanishingly small probability.

Comment: Generally speaking whether or not a random variable is continuous is not an interesting question, since the measure theoretic formulation of probability theory subsumes both PDFs and PMFs into a single construction.

Comment: OK but why can't I assign a probability to it being discrete for a particular discrete support based on the sample?

Comment: Because you don't have a prior probability telling you the probabilities of having different discrete supports.

Comment: No I'm assuming I don't know what the support is. I am suspecting that a sample size n=5 of nothing but 0s and 1s would have a lower probability of being discrete than a sample of size n=100 with nothing but 0s and 1s?

Comment: Your interpretation of it having a lower probability only makes sense in a Bayesian context though.  So if you're assigning probabilities to various supports based on your data, all you're saying is one support is more probable than another based on the data.  But that doesn't mean both don't have vanishingly small probability compared to a particular infinite support.  Since the probabiilty of the RV taking values off these discrete sets may be epsilon small.

Comment: You can't assign probabilities to various models based on your data without a prior distribution.  That's why frequentist statistics only talks about relative "likelihoods".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the difference between discrete and continuous lies in how the *population* distribution is described.

**Discrete population.** If probabilities are specified for a finite (or countable) number of values, then the distribution is discrete.
An example is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(5, .5),$ where $P(X = k) = {5 \choose k}/32,$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,4,5.$ Only the six integers from 0 to 5 (inclusive) have
probabilities. Many (not all) of the discrete distributions in common use
take integer values.

**Continuous population.** If the probability distribution is described by a density function, then it is continuous. An example is $Y \sim \mathsf{Exp}(rate=1),$ where the density
function is $f(y) = e^{-y},$ for $y > 0.$ The probability of an *interval* is
obtained by integrating the density function. The probability of any one
particular value is $0$. So in theory, it is not possible to have repeated 
values (ties) in the data. As a practical matter continuous data may have
ties, because one must round to a certain number of decimal places and two
different observations may have the same *rounded* value.

**Samples.** Given a *sample*, it is not possible to say *for sure* whether the population
from which the sample was taken is discrete or continuous. However, in practice
you can get a pretty good idea.

$(a)$ If there are more than just occasional repeated values, then the
population should ordinarily be regarded as discrete. This is especially true
if values are all integers.

$(b)$ A large sample with no repeated values should ordinarily be regarded
as having come from a continuous population. This is especially true if the
observations are not integers (or otherwise regularly spaced).

**Practical importance.** One kind of statistical application in which the difference between
a discrete and a continuous population is important is in the use
of nonparametric statistics that are based on ranking data. Examples, are
the Wilcoxon signed-rank and rank-sum tests. Data are assumed to be
from continuous populations so that there will be few (ideally no) ties.
Ties interfere with the computation of ranks and thus with the probability
theory underlying the test.

By contrast, a *runs* test is based on sequences
of repeated values. If s runs test is done on  continuous data, one must *artificially induce* discreteness. For example, one may look at something like
'runs above the mean (+1)' and ' runs below the mean (-1).

**Examples.** Here is a sample of 50 observations from the continuous distributio $\mathsf{Norm}(100,10).$ Values have been rounded
to the nearest 0.01. They have been sorted from smallest to largest; numbers in brackets show the index of the first observation in each row. If you 
look closely, you can see that there is a tie at 101.05. But a statistician looking at these data would suppose
that they were sampled from a continuous population. (However,
it is *possible*, however implausible, that the population consists **only** of the 49 different values we happened to observe.)

```
 [1]  63.90  78.72  80.47  84.73  85.04  85.18  87.28  88.30  90.29  91.03
[11]  92.42  92.81  93.96  95.27  95.77  96.17  96.75  96.90  97.95  98.23
[21]  98.46  98.57  98.91  98.92  99.27  99.62 100.01 100.69 101.05 101.05
[31] 101.21 102.75 102.76 103.38 103.50 103.97 104.47 105.88 106.71 107.80
[41] 107.83 107.97 108.06 108.57 109.09 111.16 112.39 113.53 113.82 115.30
```

Here is a sample of 20 observations from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=100),$ a discrete distribution taking only integer values. There are only three ties among the 20 values (at 98, 104, and 110). However, because all values are integers,
I doubt that a statistician would assume that the ties are the result of rounding data from a continuous distribution. (But of course, rounding is a *possibility;*
sometimes continuous data are rounded to integers, although that is not usually
good practice.)

```
 [1]  79  81  92  93  95  96  97  98  98  99
[11] 101 104 104 105 106 110 110 111 115 116
```